# Error on pip install indexer and python3 -m pip install indexer

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, installation, indexer

I am trying to install indexer but getting the below error. Can anyone please help me with this?

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-gnyzkvn1/indexer/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-gnyzkvn1/indexer/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-gnyzkvn1/indexer/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-gnyzkvn1/indexer/
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-gnyzkvn1/indexer/setup.py", line 107
        except OSError, ex:
                      ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: `indexer` is more than 10 years old and supports Python 2 only.

Answer (score 0):

Python3 does not allow the error message separated by a comma like Python2 did.
You should use an extra print() statement.

```
except OSError as ex:
    print(ex.args)
```

As [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) say:

> ```
> try: 
>      raise Exception('spam', 'eggs')  
> except Exception as inst:
>      print(type(inst))    # the exception instance 
>      print(inst.args)     # arguments stored in .args
> ```

That's why `except OSError, ex:` gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

I run on a similar case. I was needing indexer in python 3 for library Spellcheker.

```
pip install pyspellchecker
```

I suspect if your issue is in that context perhaps helpful.